# Изменить текст RadioButton на текст, считанный из файла?

Tags: android

Я задумала написать приложение тест. Столкнулась с такой задачей, как изменить текст `RadioButton`-ов на то, что лежит у меня в `TXT` в папке `assets`?

Парсить файл я уже научилась, только выводить могу данные через `ТextView`, а с `RadioButton` беда и в гугле как назло ничего найти не могу.

P.S. Понимаю, что готовых решений никто не даст, подскажите хоть где искать или что делать приблизительно, дальше я сама.

Comment: У вас текст не меняется? Или что именно не получается?

Comment: Покажите как вы пытались на радиоКнопках менять текст.

Answer (score 3):

Как бы это странно не звучало, но [`RadioButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html) наследуется от `TextView`. И чтобы установить текст в [`RadioButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html), нужно с ним сделать то же самое, что и с `TextView`:

```
radioButton.setText("radio button new text");
```